# Difference Between More Kernel and One Kernel More Dimension

Tags: c, cuda

Is there a difference between calling two kernel for task that can do in big sized grid

```
1.
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
   dim3 dimBlock(16, 8);
   dim3 dimGrid(1,1);
   FooTask<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(MatrixA,MatrixB)
}
2.
dim3 dimBlock(16, 16);
dim3 dimGrid(1,1);
FooTask<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(MatrixA,MatrixB)
```

and is there a cost for creating kernel on Gpu.

Comment: Maybe. Try it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

Kernels have a launch overhead of a few microseconds at least.  If the work done by your kernels was very small/short, then I would expect the first case to take longer.  If the kernels are doing a large amount of work, the difference should be small, percentage-wise.

Note that `<<<32,1>>>` and `<<<64,1>>>` are very poor choices in grid configuration if you want to exploit the power of a GPU.  Grid (launch) configurations that run only a single thread per block may leave over 95% of the GPU capability unused.

Answer (score 1):

When running the two kernels in a loop (and in the same stream), they are serialized. That is, the GPU must complete all the calculations for the first launch of the kernel before the second launch. The GPU must also flush all the results written by the first launch out to global memory before the second launch (because CUDA guarantees that results written by a kernel are visible to later kernels).

If you launch a single kernel with more threads instead, the GPU is free to schedule more threads in parallel if there is capacity and there is more opportunity to reuse values read from global memory by the kernel.

In general, the kernel launch overhead is negligible.